# Django-hosts redirect form non-www to www

Tags: django, redirect, hosts

The site generates different URLs that all look like http://example.com/'somepath'. What I want to do is to redirect users from http://example.com/'somepath' to http://www.example.com/'somepath'. As I found out it's possible to do with django-hosts. 

As it's said in instructions I have the following in settings.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.example.com', 'example.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...,
   'django_hosts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
   'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddleware',
   ...
   'django_hosts.middleware.HostsResponseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'appname.urls'
ROOT_HOSTCONF = 'appname.hosts'
DEFAULT_HOST = 'www'
DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = "http://www.example.com"
PARENT_HOST = "example.com"
```

In hostsconf/urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import wildcard_redirect

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<path>.*)', wildcard_redirect),
]
```

In hostsconf/views:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = getattr(settings, "DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL", "http://www.example.com")

def wildcard_redirect(request, path=None):
    new_url = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL
    if path is not None:
        new_url = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL + "/" + path
    return HttpResponseRedirect(new_url)
```

But looks like it doesn't work because if I go to http://example.com/'somepath' it returns "400 Bad Request" and http://www.example.com/'somepath' points to the correct destination. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try the default settings **PREPEND_WWW**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#prepend-www

Comment: and what you get in this? 400 you can get if not set ALLOWED_HOSTS, you sure that you did it? show trace back


P.S. remove django-hosts, he did not want to redirect to www

Comment: I set allowed_hosts and PREPEND_WWW returns the same error "400 Bad Request"

Comment: show traceback, but not error code, because you need to find where and why the error is caused, see logs